# f bounded and measurable implies L-integrable?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I need some help with a the following statement:

Show: Is $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ a bounded and measurable function, so f is L-integrable on $[0,1]$

Can I show it with the Lebesgue Theorem (dominated convegence)?

b) Show: If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of bounded measurable functions on $[0,1]$ and convgerts uniformly on $[0,1]$ to $f$, so f is L-integrable on [0,1] and

$\lim int_{[0,1]} f_n d\lambda = \int_{[0,1]} f d\lambda $ ?
If my idea for a) is right, cant i take the same proof?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Have been asked to use DCT or is it your own idea? a) is entirely trivial and one doen't use DCT for this.

Comment: Haven't been asked, was my idea

Comment: Maybe it is helpful to prove even more.  If $|f| \le M$ then $f$ is integrable, and $\int_{[0,1]} |f|\;d\lambda \le M$.

Answer (score 1):

For (a) I would think about the fact that f is bounded and you're integrating on a set of finite measure. 
For (b) the dominated convergence theorem should do the work for you but try and see how to satisfy the required hypotheses.

Comment: Im not sure how to do it, can i say that if f is bounded and completet so it is compact so it is L-integrable, im not sure what i have to show explict for L-integrable

Comment: b) let $f_n$ be  a  seqeunce $L([0,1])$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$=$f(x)$ for nearly all  $x \in[0,1]$, and there is a  $g(x)\in[0,1]$ with  $|f_n(x)|\le g(x)$ because f is bounded  and then with Lebesgues Theorem $\Rightarrow f\in L([0,1])$

Answer (score 1):

For (b) we know f will be bounded since the convergence is uniform (uniform sequence of bounded functions will converge to a bounded function) so $f$ is bounded and measurable. From part (a) we know f is integrable.  To show the existence of an integrable function that dominates every term in the sequence you can take $M=sup\{|f_n|:n \in \mathbf{N}, x\in [0,1]\}$ this M will exist and be finite and will dominate all the $f_n$'s at every point in the interval. Now define $g(x)=M \chi_{[0,1]}$ this will be integrable and will allow us to invoke Dominate Convergence.

Comment: so a) is clear becaue its a finite measure?